# Getting all table rows and returning them using an XPath query in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, xpath, casperjs

I'm using Casper.js to automate a regular upload. I've managed to upload the file and check if it's valid, but I'd like to parse the table which is returned if there's errors, but I get the error `[error] [remote] findAll(): invalid selector provided "[object Object]":Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12`. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
casper.then(function() {
    if (this.fetchText('.statusMessageContainer').match(/Sorry, the file did not pass validation. Please review the validation errors in the report below/)) {
        this.echo("Upload failed!", "ERROR");
        errors = this.evaluate(function() {
            var errorRows = __utils__.findAll({
                type: 'xpath',
                path: '//table[@id="uploadTable"]/tr[position()>1]'
            });
            return Array.prototype.forEach.call(errorRows, function(e) {
                return e;
            });
        });
        this.echo(JSON.stringify(errors));
    } else {
        this.echo("Upload successful", "INFO");
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a tag named after me.  I never thought this day would come. \*sniff sniff\*.

Answer (score 2):

While you probably have an XPath syntax error, you must know that you cannot return DOM elements from a closure passed to the `evaluate()` method; you have to convert your `NodeList` and `HTMLelement` instances to some native Javascript types, eg. Arrays, Objects, strings, etc…

Also, there's a convenient [`getElementsByXPath()` method in the ClientUtils module](http://casperjs.org/#phantom_Casper_ClientUtils_getElementsByXPath) you can use from the `__utils__` instance automatically injected in every page your load:

```
casper.then(function() {
    if (this.fetchText('.statusMessageContainer').match(/Sorry, the file did not pass validation. Please review the validation errors in the report below/)) {
        this.echo("Upload failed!", "ERROR");
        var errors = this.evaluate(function() {
            var errorRows = __utils__.getElementsByXPath('//table[@id="uploadTable"]/tr[position()>1]');
            return Array.prototype.map.call(errorRows, function(e) {
                return e.innerText; // let's get node text instead of HTMLelement!
            });
        });
        this.echo(JSON.stringify(errors));
    } else {
        this.echo("Upload successful", "INFO");
    }
});
```

You can also use the [ClientUtils bookmarklet](http://casperjs.org/#bookmarklet) to test your selectors right within your browser console as well. For example here, click the bookmarklet and execute this in the js console:

```
__utils__.getElementsByXPath('//table[@id="uploadTable"]/tr[position()>1]')
```

Then you'll see if your selector is correct (it works by my side — I mean it is syntactically correct).

Comment: Ah, cool. I have had a look and it does seem my xPath was wrong. I've now got:

`var errorRows = __utils__.getElementsByXPath("//table[@id='uploadTable']/tbody/tr[position()>1]");`

But I'm now getting an error the on the `this.evaluate` part, namely `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function`. Any ideas?

Comment: Very hard to help without seeing the real code :/ Could you please paste some actual code somewhere, even privately?

Answer (score 0):

Well from your error it appears there is something wrong with your selector.
It's setup correctly from what I can see, except for one thing: Try changing `'//table[@id="uploadTable"]/tr[position()>1]'` to `'//table[@id='uploadTable']/tr[position()>1]'` (change "" to '')

Other than that, your XPath looks syntactically correct, so I'm not sure why it would qualify as an invalid selector.

Comment: No joy there unfortunately. Think it might be a problem with my Javascript or CasperJS (probably the former!)