# CasperJS getElementsByXPath only returning first element

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I use the following code to get all table cells in the first table row. I'd like to then check the innerHTML of every single table cell. But in the object returned by this function only the first table cell is actually there, all the other properties are null:

```
firstRow = this.evaluate(function () {
    return __utils__.getElementsByXPath('//tbody/tr[1]/td');
});

utils.dump(firstRow);
```

The output from utils.dump is:

```
[
    {
        "abbr": "",
        "align": "",
        "attributes": {...}
    },
    null,
    null,
    null
]
```

I also tried with **utils**.findAll and it was the same. How can I get all the matched elements?

Comment: the first answer here answers my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740907/getting-all-table-rows-and-returning-them-using-an-xpath-query-in-casperjs

Comment: Have a look at this, that should help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740907/getting-all-table-rows-and-returning-them-using-an-xpath-query-in-casperjs

Answer (score 4):

With Casper/PhantomJS `evaluate()` functions, you have to map native DOM elements and lists of elements to something JSON-serializable:

```
var firstRow = this.evaluate(function () {
    var elements = __utils__.getElementsByXPath('//tbody/tr[1]/td');
    return [].map.call(elements, function(element) {
        return element.outerHTML;
    });
});

utils.dump(firstRow);
```